# Add a Form in Table Row Dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, html

In my application we have User details section which is designed using Table layout now we want to allow user to add details for multiple user and allow him to add this layout dynamically.

I checked to add layout dynamically and I am able to add each components separately but not complete table.

Please suggest how can we make user details section as single table row and add new row each time user wants to on some button click.

Comment: You would start by writing some code

Comment: Where is the relevant source code to your question and what have you tried to far? Please update your question to display the relevant source code and include your attempt(s), please try explain the issues you face with your current attempt. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, then you can append a row to table as follows:

```
var markup = "<tr><td>" + name + "</td></tr>";
$("table tbody").append(markup);
```

Comment: jQuery isn't tagged in this question.